# Pasar valor de un arreglo php a jquery

Tags: php, jquery, array

primero que nada me disculpo si esta duplicado el tema o no me doy a entender correctamente

tengo el siguiente codigo en php

```
<?php
$qry_res=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM animalestipo");
$j=0;
while ($rowres=mysqli_fetch_array($qry_res)) {
    $elementos[$j]=$rowres['Nombre'];
}?>
```

y quiero recibirlo en otra pagina js con el siguiente codigo

```
 var i = 0;
var arreglo = new Array();

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mas").click(function(){
        i++
        var j = $("#j").val();
        for (var k =1; k < j; k++) {
            arreglo[k] = $("#elementos[k]").val();
            console.log(arreglo[k]);
        }
        agregar(i);     
    });
});
```

lo que quiero es en la pagina js obtener los valores del arreglo guardado en la pagina php

alguna idea?? Me disculpo de antemano por los errores pues soy nuevo y quizas no es el mejor metodo

Comment: Lo que se suele hacer en estos casos es utilizar AJAX. Este tipo de comunicación te permite comunicar cliente y servidor de manera asíncrona. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. Básicamente su funcionamiento es: lanzas la llamada al php desde js, el php devuelve algo, el js lo recupera y entonces utilizas la respuesta para lo que necesites.

Comment: Desde mi punto de vista lo mejor sería hacer un pequeño servicio REST con PHP y consumirlo (en formato JSON o XML) vía AJAX con JS.

¿Utilizas alguna librería para PHP o estás picando la página a mano?

Answer (score 0):

si la estoy haciendo a mano a la pagina y tengo algo como el siguiente esquema

lista.php (esta envia la consulta y lo que recibe lo muestra en un select y un boton para agregar una nueva fila que llama a rellena.js)
rellena.js (aqui utilizo ajax para enviar datos a rellenatabla.php y la respuesta la devuelvo a lista.php) tengo el siguiente codigo en pagina.js

```
function agregar(consulta){
    $.ajax({
        url:'includes/rellenatabla.php',
        type:'POST',
        dataType:'html',
        data:{consulta: consulta},
        })
    .done(function (respuesta) {
        $("#tabla tbody").append(respuesta);
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log('Failed');
    })
}
var i = 1;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mas").click(function(){
        i++;        
        agregar(i);     
    });
});
```

el tema es que en la pagina rellenatabla.php tengo que volver a hacer la consulta para hacer el select dinamico para luego pasarlo a lista.php

lo que quiero evitar es que cada que apreto el boton agregar nuevo select en lista.php se realice la consulta en rellenatabla.php

espero haberme explicado bien